# ASP.NET Zero Session Management

Tags: session, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, neodynamic

I am completely new to ASP.NET Core and DDD (domain-driven design). I recently purchased the [ASP.NET Zero](https://aspnetzero.com/) startup template to ease the pain and learning curve of getting started. I love the project, but I am having difficulty with session state.

I use third-party components in our application, like the [Neodynamic products](https://www.neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/aspnet-core/download/).

I need a way to pass the current session ID and protocol to several of these components from their respective controllers. In ASP.NET MVC, it was relatively easy with `HttpContext.Session.Id` and `HttpContext.Request.Scheme`. This seems to be a bit more confusing in ASP.NET Core.

Can someone get me started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session` package provides middleware for managing session state.

Call `AddSession()` and `UseSession()` in your `Startup` class:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession();

        // ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // ...

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(...);
    }
}
```

Reference: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Answer (score 0):

`UserManager` class gives you the current user's info.

Example:

```
 public async Task<string> GetCurrentUserName()
 {
      var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(AbpSession.GetUserId().ToString());
      return user.UserName;
 }
```

`IAbpSession AbpSession` can also give you useful info which you use by inheriting from `ApplicationService` abstract class. `Interface IAbpSession` is defined in Abp.dll.

Inject `IAbpSession` and `UserManager` in the required class wherever you want to get info.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private readonly IAbpSession _abpSession;
    private readonly UserManager _userManager;

    public TestClass(
        IAbpSession abpSession,
        UserManager userManager)
    {
        _abpSession = abpSession;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can Implement IAbpSession as shown above and it works fine where I am stuck is that I need to pass an Absolute Url along with the current Session ID  for postback. Here is an example using the Neodynamic WebPrintClient

 ` public ActionResult index() 
{
            ViewData["WCPPDetectionSript"] =
                Neodynamic.SDK.Web.WebClientPrint.CreateWcppDetectionScript(
                    Url.Action("ProcessReqeust", "WebClientPrintAPI", null, Url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Scheme),
                    Url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Session.Id);  Return View();

} `